# Liquibase script fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, glassfish, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I have a glassfish application which creates its DB schema with liquibase. I have migrated the same application to Spring Boot. I did not drop the DB schema. When I deploy the Spring application and the liquibase scripts run, I get

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

when executing the changeset for creating one of the tables.

I need to specify there is no change in the liquibase scripts and the database changelog lock is acquired successfully.

Shouldn't it skip all the table creation steps? I plug in the same application to the same DB. Have you encountered this situation before?

UPDATE: is it possible that this might be related to the MD5 sum stored in the changelog file ? So the md5 computed by the new application doesn't match the one computed by the old one and the scripts are triggered, causing the obvious exception ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have a checksum difference - that would cause a different error message. What I think is likely is that the DATABASECHANGELOG table has a different changelog path for the changes than what is being reported by Liquibase.

Changesets are identified by 3 things - the changeset id, the author, and the path. When Liquibase is deciding whether a changeset from a changelog should be deployed to a particular database, it looks at the DATABASECHANGELOG table and retrieves that information, compares it with the information in the changelog file, and doeesn't try to deploy anything that matches up. In this case, I think it detects differences in the path and tries to re-deploy the change.

Comment: Thank you @SteveDonie, that was my problem. Upgrading the liquibase version led to the changelog path to be built in a slightly different way. So the change set would be applied. The solution was to specify the logFileName attribute in the .xml file.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel this was a correct answer, please 'accept the answer' as correct here.